# C++ iPhone Compiler Problems

Tags: c++, iphone

I've written a simple code to practice some stuff, but it's not running as it's supposed to.
I'm programming on my iPhone just for fun and l'm using an app called c/c++ offline compiler which seems to work really well.

Anyway, I wrote a program to display numbers, and if the number is less than 5 digits, in each empty space display a star. Then next to that, display the memory address.

There are two questions I have. First, why are the stars not displaying when I run this. Second, each time run it, the memory addresses are different. Is this because of the compiler, or because of how the iPhone's memory works?

Source Code:

```
//c plus plus program 1

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (void){

    for(int i=0; i<150;i+=30){

    cout.width(5);
    cout.fill('*');

    cout<<i<< "="<<&i <<endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that address of `i` is changing each time you run your program. As I know it is because of how system works with memory. Why did you think it will place your program in the same part every time? :-)

I tried you code in http://cpp.sh only and stars were shown:

```
****0=0xffcde9dc
***30=0xffcde9dc
***60=0xffcde9dc
***90=0xffcde9dc
**120=0xffcde9dc
```

Note, that all after second `<<` was not took into consideration when output width was determined. So first of all to investigate the problem I would try something like

```
int main (void) {
    cout.width(5);
    cout.fill('*');
    cout << 1 << endl;
    cout << 2 << endl;
}
```

to understand if it compiler problem or not.

Comment: Well, whenever I program in visual studio, it always starts from one address and goes from there, so every time I run the program it's in the same address. Wasn't sure if it was a Windows v. Apple thing. Or, desktop v. Mobile thing. Or, even just a difference in compilers.